# Sizing a mixer circuit

Tags: circuit-design, mixer

Here's the question:

[image]

Here's my attempt:

[image]

[image]

The table where i got the transistors values:

[image]

And here's the circuit i implemented in LTSpice:

[image]

[image]

The simulation results was a failure.... The output voltage is no where near 5Mhz. What did i do wrong?

Also i'm not even sure what capacitors C1 and C2 do and how to size them. I just added some values that i found on some website. Do they change the gain (the one i used)?

Edit:

Well, already kinda solve it:

[image]

[image]

I just need to find the mixer noise, should i take into account the biasing part of the circuit and the current mirror?

Comment: What did you do in order to work out the biasing? (I'm not seeing anything good in the schematic. But I may be missing something.)

Comment: @jonk i did a current mirror. That was the first thing i did

Comment: How have you tried to filter out the IF from the other products? How long do you have to run the simulation to see a full cycle of the IF? I can see a pattern representing a fraction of a cycle in the green trace; are you sure there's anything wrong at all?

Comment: Your bias network looks odd. What is M5 supposed to be doing?

Comment: @user_1818839 Yeah you were right, i had to change the the simulation time. Also had to do some changes, you can see that in the new edit part

Comment: @DaveTweed I made some changes. I think it works fine now, you can see what i did in the new edit

Comment: Better, but it's highly non-linear. Reducing the signal amplitude may help, or see other comments about biasing.

Comment: @user_1818839 The biasing is made up by the current mirror transistors (M5 and M4) and those voltage dividers that are connect to the input and LO.

Comment: @user_1818839 Also i would like to add that if i drop the input signal amplitude below 0.4V the IF signal goes to 0.... Why does that happen? If i put a higher amplitude the signal just gets compressed